# error while compiling in Fujitsu COBOL 3.0

Tags: cobol

while compiling in Fujitsu COBOL 3.0 i m getting a error saying c://cobol/sample2.cbl file does not exist or having an invalid file name or file is used by another program. but the file is present in the exact location and is not used by any other prog. can any1 tell what could be the problem

Comment: I can't. but just reading the word COBOL made me break out in laughter. Thanks for brightening my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You must first close your editor before attempting to compile your source.  This reference will give you an overview.

http://www.wiley.com/college/info/stern318817/resources/compilers/comp_comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

Also be sure that you don't have Fujitsu COBOL 3.0 installed in a path with LFNs.